# EF Core 5.0 where predicate is ignored when in stored in variable

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

after update to EF Core 5.0 I've notice long running query.
Maybe I found EF Core 5.0 bug, but maybe it's a breaking change I didn't found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes.

I have a function, that takes "where" predicate as a parameter, so this is something I cannot easily rewrite.

**Code that works:**

```
var reps = ctx.Reports.AsNoTracking()
                                  .Include(r => r.ReportColumns)
                                  .Where(r => r.Name == "ListOfCustomers")
                                  .ToList();
```

and generates correct query (WHERE clause inluded):

```
SELECT [r].[ReportID], [r].[AdvancedFilterPurpose] -- ommited columns
      FROM [report].[Reports] AS [r]
      LEFT JOIN [report].[ReportColumns] AS [r0] ON [r].[ReportID] = [r0].[ReportID]
      WHERE [r].[Name] = N'ListOfCustomers'
      ORDER BY [r].[ReportID], [r0].[ReportColumnID]
```

**Code that doesn't work:**

```
Func<Db.Model.Report, bool> a = (r) => r.Name == "ListOfCustomers";
var reps = ctx.Reports.AsNoTracking()
              .Include(r => r.ReportColumns)
              .Where(a)
              .ToList();
```

and generates query without WHERE clause

```
SELECT [r].[ReportID], [r].[AdvancedFilterPurpose] -- ommited columns  
      FROM [report].[Reports] AS [r]
      LEFT JOIN [report].[ReportColumns] AS [r0] ON [r].[ReportID] = [r0].[ReportID]
      ORDER BY [r].[ReportID], [r0].[ReportColumnID]
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Replace type Func<Db.Model.Report, bool> by Expression<Func<Db.Model.Report,bool>>.

This won't work: `Func<Db.Model.Report, bool> a = (r) => r.Name == "ListOfCustomers"`

This will work: `Expression<Func<Db.Model.Report, bool>> a = (r) => r.Name == "ListOfCustomers"`